# I do not know why angular6 app.component.html page keeps on replacing another page

Tags: angular

For hours I cannot get **angular 6** to display the content of **login.component.html** when called from browser.
In my **angualr 6** application I have the following directory and registration works fine

```
src/app/app.component.css
src/app/app.component.html
src/app/app.component.spec.ts
src/app/app.module.ts
src/app/app.register.ts
src/app/app.register.service.ts
```

I can access the content in the browser via **localhost:4200**

Now I want to create a new directory called **LOGIN** so that I can create Login files.
So inside **app** directory, I created a directory called **login** with the following files in it.

```
src/app/login/login.component.css
src/app/login/login.component.html
src/app/login/login.component.ts
src/app/login/login.ts
src/app/login/login.service.ts
```

When I access the page via **localhost:4200/login/ or  via localhost:4200/login/login.component.html**

Instead of the app to load content of **login.component.html** it will go and load **app.component.html**  which is not supposed.
what am I doing wrong.   should I post all the entire code for all these. Please I need help

for example inside **login.component.ts** i have below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './login/login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login/login.component.css'],



})
```

Here is my update. Am performing routing within **app.module.ts**  which shows
error **Error in src/app/app.module.ts(38,7): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/app.module.ts(38,13): error TS1005: ',' expected.** after adding the following line of code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'product/id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: RegisterLoginComponent
  }
],
```

Here is entire updates of **app.module.ts** which displays error above

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';

import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail/product-detail.component';

import { RegisterLoginComponent } from './register-login/register-login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 FileSelectDirective,
 ProductListComponent,
 ProductDetailComponent,
 RegisterLoginComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,

RouterModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'product/id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: RegisterLoginComponent
  }
],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What is in your routing file?

Comment: You don't appear to have added routing for a URL for the login page which would then load the login component. You probably want to look into the routing module.

Comment: I have no routing yet. just new to angular. Please can you provide example of the routing and directory where it should be added

Comment: You should really take a look at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Comment: Have you looked through the official Angular tutorial and documentation on routing? https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @jmarkatti Can u please create a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cskdrk

Comment: Please can you see the above code. I have updated the Routing configuration inside app.module.ts but it shows error during compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem.

//app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';

import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail/product-detail.component';

import { RegisterLoginComponent } from './register-login/register-login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'product/id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'reglogin',
    component: RegisterLoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 FileSelectDirective,
 ProductListComponent,
 ProductDetailComponent,
 RegisterLoginComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,

RouterModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


export class AppModule { }
```